# Passing liquid file to Liquid::Template.parse

Tags: ruby, liquid

Right now I am able to do this:

```
@template = Liquid::Template.parse("hi {{name}}") # Parses and compiles the template
p @template.render('name' => 'tobi')
```

However, how can I call `Liquid::Template` with a file that I have called `template.liquid` that has the content:

```
hi {{name}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File.read() returns the whole file as a string, so you can write:

```
template = Liquid::Template.parse(
             File.read("template.liquid")
           )
```

Comment: I realize that when I do this, instead of ``hi toby``, I see ``hi tobi\n`` why is that?

Comment: @HommerSmith, Some OS's automatically add a "\n" to the end of a file.  You can remove a trailing "\n" with chomp(): `File.read("template.liquid").chomp`.  If there is no trailing "\n", then chomp doesn't remove anything.

Comment: I am surprised Liquid doesn't offer a way to parse from File directly though.

Comment: @HommerSmith, I checked the Liquid docs before posting my answer, but the docs don't indicate you can do that.